# How to display ESRI shapefile in Android

Tags: shapefile, android

It's the first time I work with Android and ESRI shapefiles. I tried to find but could not find any tutorials to display ESRI shapefile in Android.

Somebody can help me about this?

Comment: is there any possibility for displaying the multiple shapefiles without using the googlemaps in the background in a iOS device r objective C,i directly want to display a shape file with the lat and long for a specified location.
Ex:nevada,Mexico,brazil,india etc etc

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS.Please ask this as separate question...thanks

Answer (score 8):

Quantum GIS for Android is one option.

http://android.qgis.org

Here is more info: http://www.opengis.ch/android-gis

Answer (score 5):

There is one app called "SHP Viewer"

Details please click [here](http://androgeoid.com/2011/03/view-gis-shapefiles-on-android-with-shp-viewer/)

Comment: thank you Sunil. That is my goal, but this app is not find in Google Play Store.

Answer (score 2):

**ArcGIS for Android (Official)**

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/smartphone-apps/01ww00000004000000.htm

(reading the reviews the iOS app is more stable than the android version)

Under 'Map and service support'

It clearly states

> "Shapefiles, CSV, and GPX files (only when added to ArcGIS Online
>   maps)"
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/smartphone-apps/01ww00000006000000.htm

The App is available on Google Play here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esri.android.client

Looking to build your own app the Android SDK is available here:

http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgis-android/sdk

Answer (score 2):

I've tried several apps -

- Shapefile Reader (which doesn't seem to be available on Google Play
  anymore)
- CSF (Create Shape File)
- Shapefile over Map

All have their pluses and minuses.

Comment: Shapefile Reader - as the name implies, there's no editing capability. Also, it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore, given that that it's not in Google Play.

Comment: CSF - can create a new file, but can display only one point at a time on the map, and only in the lat/long format. SoM - displays points on the map, but limited coordinate systems (WGS84 and lat/long).

Answer (score 2):

convert to kml first and use [geopaparazzi](http://code.google.com/p/geopaparazzi/)

Answer (score 1):

I tried some steps to do:

- Using Stream to Read Shapefile
- Then, I used the image object to display shapefile (using .canvas libary from Android and Java)

...

I was successful in Java MIDP, then I tried in Android.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SpatiaLite database in android or ios. visit https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index. You could do spatial queries and fetch geometries from database display them on either Google Maps, Osmdroid or any other maps like Maps-forge.

Answer (score 0):

you can also consider Mappt [www.mappt.com.au](http://www.mappt.com.au) where you can load Shapefiles, JP2's and also KML and KMZ.